# SQL Joins in more than one table, with joins based on each row

Tags: sql

I need to get values from a table, Table A, 8 rows in Table A,
and use the id in each row in Table A, to get data from Table B, and Table C,
and store those data in an array.

This is what i mean:

```
Select id, name from table A --This returns 8 rows, which is the base table.

Select rate, review from table B --this returns 5 rows, and i store this 5 rows in an array and i append it to first row in table A

Select rate, review from table C --this returns 5 rows, and i store this 5 rows in an array and i append it to first row in table A
```

So basically,
i'm doing a request that will need to fetch rows from two different tables,
and add it to the first row of that base table, as i make 8 rows of the base table.

This is how to it looks when i returned it as a json data:

```
"Rows": {
         "Rows0": {
             "ID": "524",
             "Name": "Value 1",
             "reviews": {
                 "name": "review for row value 0",
                 "timing": [
                     {
                         "day": "Sunday",
                         "Timing": "5:00PM"
                     },
                     {
                         "day": "Monday",
                         "Timing": "5:00PM"
                     },
                     {
                         "day": "Tuesday",
                         "Timing": "5:00PM"
                     }
                 ],
                 "day_showing": "Tuesday",
                 "recordid": "54570",
             }
         },
         "Rows1": {
             "ID": "789",
             "Name": "Value 1",
             "reviews": {
                 "name": "review for row value 1",
                 "timing": [
                     {
                         "day": "Sunday",
                         "Timing": "5:00PM"
                     },
                     {
                         "day": "Monday",
                         "Timing": "5:00PM"
                     },
                     {
                         "day": "Tuesday",
                         "Timing": "5:00PM"
                     }
                 ],
                 "day_showing": "Tuesday",
                 "recordid": "54570",
             }
         }
.....and more rows
```

Is there a way for me to use joins, and join these three tables together internally.
So that i don't have to loop through each row and append two tables,
because this code is inefficient,
as i return the first row,
like 8 different, 8 rows are appended to the first row and returned as an array from two different tables.
I need someone to help shed more light on this.
I' looking for the best SQL Code Construct to use, thanks.

Comment: That's what i need to do. The thing is the 5 rows from table B and table C will be returned for each row in Table A. The method i came up with makes the code, and website site run very slow, i know there's another SQL Code Construct i can use, i'm just not sure which one

Comment: It will be useful if you provide tables structure and some insert statements. And also, what specific language are you working with?
My first guess is you're looking for `joins` and `group_concat()`.